# Using annotation in Enterprise Geodatabase

Tags: arcmap, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, annotation, vb.net

I have a problem with annotation In an Enterprise Geodatabase.

In the database I have:

1. parcelle : a geometry table that contain polygons
2. personne : a table contain parcel's owners
3. pll_personne : is the relationship (n,n) between the (1) & (2)

[image]

How do I display parcels with annotation Name of their owners (see picture)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing your data in PostgreSQL your best bet is probably using a query layer.  You should be able to define a query that joins Personne and Parcelle table through pll_parcelle and includes the names of the parcelle and owner.  You can then join this table to your Parcelle layer to use in labeling.

Comment: one parcel has more than one owner so i can create a table that has columns (id_pll,owners) and in onwners  i will put data like this (owner1 concat owner2 ).....the problem is  it will be in one line (owner1 owner2 owner3).

Comment: When you are concatenating the owner names you could try putting a carriage return or new line character between each owner name.

Comment: do you think it will be saved in database with the return to new line ?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you are asking, but you should be able to save the concatenated names separated with carriage returns although I am not familiar with PostGres